# Re-using a google form sent data, avoiding entering all data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am building a Google form to manage summer camp subscriptions. Each request must enclose parents and child data.
The problem is, if a family wants to subscribe more than one child, the process must start from scratch and all parents data must be entered again. Could there be a way to reload (also with a Google Apps script) to form with partially prefilled data based on the previously sent data?
Such as "do you want to send another request" question right before the submit, if yes, reload the form with pre-filled data...
Keep in mind that the response sheet must contain **one row per each child**....
Any idea?

Comment: I guess summer camp subscriptions have finished but please have a look to a [simple form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd7SQxVrHwpe7-begGire6DhoqrWiykEJyJ8qVN5_h9gGo24A/viewform) I prepared. You get results using a single query. If it suits your needs I will turn it to an answer and you can use it for your next subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for adding your thoughts! Is it possible to view the logic behind the form?

Comment: Each parent fills just 1 form, his/her details once plus one section for each child. This way you avoid _starting the process from scratch having all parents data entered again_ or _prefilled data_. **One form for all their children**.

Comment: Did you ever try out the form. Does it fulfill your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a regular question to ask for sending another request but the pre-filled form will not be shown immediately if you use a "regular" Google Apps Script.

A "regular" Google Apps Script will use on form submit event to create the pre-filled URL. It could post the URL somewhere or send it through email.

You could implement a "hack" that capture the HTTP POST request made by the Google Form respondent view but this could be very convoluted. Maybe as a challenge for Google Apps Script / Google Forms fans could be interesting. I did that few years ago for a project but the use case completely different, maybe it now works with current version of Google Forms and I don't think that will be able to make a simplified version soon.

An intermediate solution could be to embed the form on a web application that checkouts for new submissions from the active user.